# How to get Facebook User ID from Facebook Username or link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The graph API does not seem to work and states that

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (the_username)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "AVC680GleTP"
  }
}
```

However this site: https://lookup-id.com apparently can get the Facebook User id given the link. What could be the flow to get the Facebook User ID using username or link?

Comment: I'm looking even for a workaround if Graph API cannot allow this

Comment: There is no work around.

Comment: @WizKid the website linked in this question can get the Facebook user id

Comment: They are scraping which is not allowed